# "No one had told Smith about {there would be / there being} a lecture the following day."

Tags: prepositions, complements

> No one had told Smith about __________ a lecture the following day．
>
> A．there would be 
> B．there being

Could you tell me why teachers suggest the correct answer is B rather than A? I personally prefer A, as A is clearer than B for me to understand the context.

Comment: You seem to have multiple teachers. What did they tell you?

Comment: They told me that only "there being" can be put as a prepositional complement for the preposition "about", however, I believe"there would be" is also admissible as a complement clause.

Comment: Plus I met this sentence from a corpus(http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/): And, again, it looks like were talking about there will be some by the end of the year, but its entirely unclear how many federal permits for new deep water drilling will be issued by that time.

Comment: The reason I asked the above quesiton was to guide you to make a better question. Please include your comments in the question and it will look much better and more on-topic. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a confused new language learner. If I had made the question in this way—Can "there would be" be used to lead a complement clause for prepositions, such as "about"，would this one have been checked better?

Comment: Definitely and actually that is a very good question. You will learn more about this community if you take this linked [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). :)

Comment: @Rathony, chenyi zhou, have done an answer below (Rathony, I'm still working on the very long preposition answer, I promise!)

Comment: @chenyizhou Some prepositions take finite clauses as Complements. Some grammars call such prepositions subordinating conjunctions. Verbs like *tell* can also take finite clauses as complements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preposition before a that-clause is dropped. So it can only be

1 No one had told Smith (that) there would be a lecture the following day

Or

2 No one had told Smith about there being a lecture the following day.

The normal formulation would be 1. 2 is a bit stilted.

Answer (score 4):

It's so much easier to see this when you fill in the blank.

> A) No one had told Smith about **there being** a lecture the following day

This reads fine to me.

> B) No one had told Smith about **there would be** a lecture the following day

Adding `would` removes the need for the `ing` on `being`.  This change is fine.

To me B is screaming for one more word:

> C) No one had told Smith about **how** there would be a lecture the following day

Sure C is full of froth and bubble but it doesn't set my teeth on edge like B does.

B also can get by with one less word

> D) No one had told Smith <strike>about</strike> there would be a lecture the following day

Comment: Voting for ''D''.

Comment: B seems to have a "be" .B: No one had told Smith about there would  be a lecture the following day. Does this sentence sound bad to you?  Is it because that "No one had told Smith about there being a lecture the following day" is good enough for you to understand that the lecture was given the following day after the day that news should have been told to Smith?

Comment: @chenyizhou Eep! Copy paste error.  Hang on.  Updating

Comment: @chenyizhou How do you like it now?

Comment: Thank you so much. "No one had told Smith about there being a lecture the following day" is most preferable to conventional context, since it is good enough for readers to understand the time through"the following day". Have I understood correctly? And here in this context,"there" acts like a dummy subject for "being"...

Answer (score 2):

### **Short answer**

The word *about* cannot take finite clauses as a Complement. A finite clause is a clause we can use like a sentence on its own. The word *about* CAN take *-ing* clauses as a Complement:

- *No one had told Smith about [there would be a lecture the following day]. (ungrammatical)
- No one had told Smith about [there being a lecture the following day].

For this reason the correct answer is (B).

### **Full answer**

The verb *TELL*  takes several different patterns. The verb *TELL* can take the following types of complement:

1. **Object NP**:

   *Tell [tales]*

   *Tell [Bob]*
2. **Object NP  + preposition phrase**:

   *Tell [Bob] [about the party]*
3. **Object NP + finite clause**:

   *Tell [Bob] [that we are leaving]*

It can take some other Complements too. Today,  we are interested in patterns 2 and 3. Let's look at pattern (2) first.

**(1) Object + Preposition Phrase**

The verb *TELL* takes preposition phrases headed by the preposition *about*. The preposition phrase includes the preposition *about* and also a Complement of the preposition. In the example below, the complement is the noun *the party*

- about [the party]

Different prepositions take different types of complement - just like different verbs do. So, for example, the preposition *until* can take noun phrases, adverbs and finite clauses:

- Wait until [next Christmas]. *noun phrase*
- Wait until [later]. *adverb phrase*
- Wait until [she finishes her homework]. *finite clause*

In contrast, the preposition *on* can take noun phrases, and interrogative (question) clauses. It cannot take adverbs, and it cannot take normal finite clauses, only interrogative  ones :

- We agreed on [a plan].  *noun phrase*
- We agreed on [whether to go or not]. *interrogative clause*
- *We agreed on [exactly].  *adverb phrase* (ungrammatical)
- *We agreed on [they should leave].  *normal finite clause* (ungrammatical)

The preposition *about* like the preposition *on* can take noun phrases, and interrogative clauses, but it cannot take normal finite clauses :

- We knew about [the plan].*noun phrase*
- We knew about [whether they were going to be fired]. interrogative clause
- *We know about [they were going to be fired]. *normal finite clause* (ungrammatical)

**Preposition phrases + nouns / -ing clauses:**

Almost any preposition that can take a noun as a Complement, can also take a clause using an *-ing* verb:

- We agreed on [a party].
- We agreed on [there **being** a better plan]
- I am frightened of [spiders]
- I am frightened of [**falling** out of trees]

**(2) Object + declarative content clause**

The verb *TELL* can take finite clauses with or without the word *that*. It can also take interrogative clauses. It cannot take  *-ing* clauses:

- Tell Bob [(that) the elephants have finished the buns]. *finite clause*
- Tell Bob [whether the elephants have finished their buns]. *interrogative*
- *Tell Bob [the elephants having finished their buns]. *gerund-participle* (ungrammatical)

**The Original Poster's Question**

> No one had told Smith [**about** [ __________ a lecture the following day]]．
>
> A．there would be 
>   B．there being

The Original Poster's example uses an Object NP and a preposition phrase as Complements of the verb *told*. The preposition is the word *about*. We saw that the preposition *about* cannot take finite clauses as Complement. This means that we cannot use (A) here. This is because:

- there would be a lecture the following day

... is a finite clause. We could use this as a sentence on its own. The preposition *about* CAN take noun phrases as Complement, so it can therefore also take an *-ing* clause as a Complement. This mean that we can use option (B):

- No one had told Smith about [ there **being** a lecture the following day].

Notice that this *-ing* clause is not finite. We cannot use it as a sentence on its own:

- *There being a lecture the following day. (ungrammatical)

Now, if the example didn't the preposition *about* then we use a declarative content clause. This clause would be the Complement of the verb *TELL* though, not a Complement of the preposition *about*:

- No one told Smith [there would be a lecture the following day].

If there is no *about* here, we  cannot use an *-ing* clause. The verb *TELL* does not take *-ing* clauses, as we saw above:

- *No one told Smith [there being a lecture the following day]. (ungrammatical)

---

<sub>**Note for grammar junkies**</sub>

<sub>One of the comments suggested that we could use the word *how* to make another version of the sentence. This is correct. Notice that I said that *about* can take interrogative clauses as Complement. Well we can use the interrogative word *how* after the preposition about:</sub>

<sub>- No one told Smith about [how there would be a lecture the following day].</sub>

<sub>This modern construction doesn't *really* use an interrogative clause. It is a special way of allowing prepositions to take a finite clauses as Complement. The word *how* here is a special type of subordinator that we can use in this type of situation. The word *how* has no real meaning here.</sub>

---

<sub>**References**</sub>

<sub>I originally read most of this information in the Huddleston & Pullum's *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Really, the only correct answer is:  *No one had told Smith there would be a lecture the following day.*  Everything else (including the "about") is just froth and bubble. Perhaps your teacher needs to immerse himself (or herself) in common English a bit more.

Comment: Perhaps, but that doesn't answer the question.  Perhaps the lesson was about what phrasing can follow a preposition.

Comment: What's wrong with saying *No one told me about there being a lecture this afternoon* - sounds perfectly idiomatic to me. Froth and bubble?